# How to sort "sum of 3 properties" in Elasticsearch?

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

I want to add these 3 properties (like + comment + share) and also want to sort the sum of 3 properties.

```
curl -XPUT 'http://XXX.X.XX.XXX:XXXXX/stores/' -d '{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 3, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 1 
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "store" : {
          "_all":{ "enabled": true  },
          "properties":{
            "url" : { "type" : "string", "analyzer" : "simple", "boost" : 3 },
            "title" : { "type" : "string", "boost" : 2 },
            "description" : { "type" : "string" },
            "like":{"type":"long"},
            "comment":{"type":"long"},
            "share":{"type":"long"},
            "time_added" : { "type" : "integer", "index" : "not_analyzed", "include_in_all": true }
          }
        }
    } }'
```

what is the query to do this in elasticsearch.
my elasticsearch version is 2.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below query :

```
GET /index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
           "_script": {
              "script": "doc['share'].value + doc['like'].value+doc['comment'].value",
              "type": "number",
              "order": "desc"
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

The query will fetch all data and sort them in descending order according to the total value of `(share+like+comment)`.

If you want to `sort` in ascending order then change the `order` value to `asc`.

To run `script` query, you need to add `script.engine.groovy.inline.search: on` on your `config/elasticsearch.yml` file.

Comment: Thanks sunkuet02 for fast reply, can you help me to find the "config/elasticsearch.yml" path...where the yml file.

Comment: How did you install elasticsearch ?

Comment: You can find it in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml` if you are using ubuntu and if you run it from `.zip` file then it is in there `config/elasticsearch.yml`. If you use windows then go to installation folder.

Comment: Hi sunkuet02 I found the yml file but there is some blocks.. like Cluster, Node, Paths, Memory.. should i add in Cluster or somewhere else

Comment: add the line at the last of that file without leading space. mind it "the file name must be `elasticsearch.yml`…

Comment: ERROR: [search_parse_exception] No mapping found for [_script] in order to sort on, called from sub Search::Elasticsearch::Role::Client::Direct::__ANON__

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152123/discussion-between-ganesh-and-sunkuet02).

Comment: @Ganesh, I have updated my answer. You can try with the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

above answare is correct but it was getting field error so blow query is correct.

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/stores/store/_search?pretty=true&size=3" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "sort": [
        {
           "_script": {
              "script": "doc['"'share'"'].value + doc['"'like'"'].value+doc['"'comment'"'].value",
              "type": "number",
              "order": "desc"
           }
        }
    ]
}'
```